# Android Asynctask with PHP not working

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I have been stuck for weeks.....for this problem
I am using AsynTask to send data to php and recieve a `name` to print
 but it showed this error anyone to help ??

```
12-29 19:34:12.623: D/dalvikvm(799): GC_CONCURRENT freed 188K, 11% free 2629K/2948K, paused 25ms+61ms, total 218ms
12-29 19:34:13.282: D/gralloc_goldfish(799): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-29 19:34:42.132: W/System.err(799): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-29 19:34:42.164: W/System.err(799):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
12-29 19:34:42.164: W/System.err(799):  at com.example.myweb.MainActivity.afterEffect(MainActivity.java:64)
12-29 19:34:42.164: W/System.err(799):  at com.example.myweb.toPHP.onPreExecute(toPHP.java:47)
12-29 19:34:42.164: W/System.err(799):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
12-29 19:34:42.164: W/System.err(799):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
12-29 19:34:42.164: W/System.err(799):  at com.example.myweb.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:54)
12-29 19:34:42.172: W/System.err(799):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
12-29 19:34:42.172: W/System.err(799):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
12-29 19:34:42.172: W/System.err(799):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-29 19:34:42.185: W/System.err(799):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-29 19:34:42.185: W/System.err(799):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-29 19:34:42.192: W/System.err(799):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-29 19:34:42.212: W/System.err(799):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-29 19:34:42.212: W/System.err(799):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-29 19:34:42.212: W/System.err(799):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-29 19:34:42.222: W/System.err(799):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-29 19:34:42.222: W/System.err(799):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**JSONParser.java**

```
 package com.example.myweb;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
    }
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List params) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

**toPHP.java**

```
 package com.example.myweb;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class toPHP extends AsyncTask {

    MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
    private JSONParser jsonParser;
    String email,password;
    EditText emailBox;
    EditText passwordBox;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        main.afterEffect("sending...");
        emailBox = (EditText) main.findViewById(R.id.email);
        passwordBox = (EditText) main.findViewById(R.id.password);
        email = emailBox.getText().toString();
        password = passwordBox.getText().toString();    
    }
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        toPHP userFunction = new toPHP();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = userFunction.getUserLoggedIn(email, password);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;        
     }


    public JSONObject getUserLoggedIn(String email,String password) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException{
        JSONObject json = null;
        /*
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost  post = new HttpPost("http://localhost/testand.php");
        */
        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        //post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
        //HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        //HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        //if (resEntity != null) {

            //String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();

            json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://localhost/testand.php", pairs);



        //}     
        return json;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
        String myName = json.getString("name");
        String str = myName + ", Welcome to Socionet. :) ";
        main.afterEffect(str);
    }
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myweb;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;
    EditText emailBox;
    EditText passwordBox;
    String emailId;
    String passwordId;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login1);
        emailBox   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        passwordBox   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

       button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()   {             
           public void onClick(View v)  {               
            try {
               new toPHP().execute();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();                    
            }               
           }  
         });
       }
    public void afterEffect(String str){

        TextView textV1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textV1);
        textV1.setText(str);        

    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

new errors after @hasan83 's fixes

```
12-29 21:38:27.588: W/dalvikvm(1283): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at com.example.myweb.toPHP.getUserLoggedIn(toPHP.java:99)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at com.example.myweb.toPHP.doInBackground(toPHP.java:67)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at com.example.myweb.toPHP.doInBackground(toPHP.java:1)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a new MainActivity in your AsyncTask. When you are in your MainActivity, pass the activity to the constructor of the AsyncTask. You will be able to get and update your views in the onPreExecute() method.

```
public class toPHP extends AsyncTask {
    public toPHP(Activity activity) {
    }
}
```

And in your activity:

```
new toPHP(MainActivity.this).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor so that you can pass in the current MainActivity to your AsyncTask

```
public class toPHP extends AsyncTask {

    final MainActivity main;

    public toPHP(MainActivity main) {
        this.main = main;
    }
    ...
```

then call like so

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()   {             
       public void onClick(View v)  {               
        try {
           new toPHP(MainActivity.this).execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();                    
        }               
       }  
     });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Error says it's unable to find your TextView with id of R.id.textV1. Make sure it's available in the content view :R.layout.activity_main

But the main problem is why are you doing this `MainActivity main = new MainActivity()`, in your AsyncTask. It should be passed by reference from the actual Activity.

Answer (score 0):

**Points:**

1. I don't see `@Override` keyword before `onPostExecute` and `doInBackground` methods.
2. Move the code in `onPreExecute` to `doInBackground`.
3. Send the main activity as a parameter for the `AsynkTask` execute method.
4. Catch the activity on the do doInBackground.
5. dont' declare an object of toPhp just call `getUserLoggedIn`. you are in the same class.

That's it.

```
new toPHP().execute(MainActivity.this);

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... args) {

    main = (MainActivity) args[0];
    main.afterEffect("sending...");
    emailBox = (EditText) main.findViewById(R.id.email);
    passwordBox = (EditText) main.findViewById(R.id.password);
    email = emailBox.getText().toString();
    password = passwordBox.getText().toString();
    ..
}
```

Comment: number 4 is the first line in doInBackground method.

Comment: you're a marskmen dude! But what do i keep in `onPreExecute()` ?

Comment: the method that actually work in background and the one you need to start an http request is doInBackground. "logical name for method :)". onPreExecute work on main thread which freeze the UI. you should move the code in  onPreExecute to doInBackground.

Comment: I believe you can't benefit from onPreExecute in your case. because you can only get main activity in doInBackground method. the parameters sent by execute method sent to doInBackground. not onPreExecute.

Comment: I updated one word in the answer. also don't forgot @Override keyword.

Comment: so theres no need of `onpreex` method ?

Comment: at least not in your case.

Comment: and when adding @override getting an error `method doInbackgr... of toPHP type must implement or override a supertype` @hasan83

Comment: I created a github project once for someone asked how to use asynctask   for an http request. you can check it out. https://github.com/hasanalbukhari/Android-Json-Parse-and-Structure it also show best practice where to do different things. as updating the UI and other things. check it out.

Comment: ok I think you are right. I do add @Override to my implementation because I use my own version of asynctask. got confused remove it. u can see it in the github project.

Comment: doInBackground wont call...its calling  preExecute() @hasan83

Comment: check the example here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html how you extend asynctask with parameter types. its also exists in the git hub project example.

Comment: public class HttpClientThread extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Object>

Comment: send it to my email. hasanal_bukhari@hotmail

Comment: man it's wrong to just keep updating the question for new problems. it's not a forum. you must ask new question. what if one user solved a problem and other one solved another problem. who got the right answer. send me your project I will fix it.